# adding Colon (:) in each line of the file

Tags: python, dictionary

Input :

```
126211  consecutive prog runs error logged debug core
126262  manual change memory view propagated views like variable view expression view
```

Output

```
126211 : consecutive prog runs error logged debug core
126262 : manual change memory view propagated views like variable view expression view
```

Code

```
def function_1():
    filename = open('input.txt', 'r')
    for line in filename:
        #print line
        line = line.rstrip('') 
        #line1= re.sub('[^\w ]','',line)[8:]
        #print line1
```

Problem is I need to read the first digit of each line and add a Colon (:) with space in both sides. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your output example is inconsistent. Is there supposed to be a space between the number and the colon or not?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I updated the output example. Yes, there is a space between the number and the colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split on the first whitespace encountered:

```
def function_1():
    with open('input.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            number, rest = line.split(None, 1)
            print '{} : {}'.format(number, rest.rstrip())
```

`.split(None, 1)` splits on arbitrary-width whitespace, but only once, leaving you with the number and the rest of the line in two variables.

Comment: Why not just `number + ' : ' + rest.rstrip()`

Comment: I am allergic to `+` string concatenation.. switched to `format()`. :-)

Comment: I remember someone saying that `+` may incur performance penalty.

Comment: @Elazar: yes, but for just two concatenations the function call to `''.join()` may actually be more costly. But jamylak knows all that. And readability counts too!

Comment: Personally I believe that `+` is the most readable. BTW why not use `print()` always on answers? is there any situation in which it will not work the same way for 2 and 3?

Comment: @Elazar: `print(1, 2)` in Python 2 is a very different thing from `print 1, 2`.

Comment: :-/ . I Guess I should use 2 more.

Answer (score 0):

@Martijn Pieters already gave the right answer, but just in case there are always 6 digits and 2 spaces, note that you can use `print line[:6], ':', line[8:]` too.